# Types with different parameters like function overload

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to write a type which acts as a function signature that allows to have to different set of parameters:

- The first case, the function expects a predicate.
- The second case, the function expects two parameters.

This is the example: [Link to TS PlaGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=44&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjAHhhAdsAlqAfFAvFACjACcIATdAYwENgIAuQg1DUR5NTEASjxw9YgoAHygA3APboy3XrhyTpAbgCwAKFCRYAJiQBRTtjyESEyMVAA5agFsGUANYQQEgGawDggDRQUEAO4AatQANgCu9mEoDigS-ihyClJkqhrg0DAAwhI2NhIo+oYgOPjwhYI4ojC6MJ5cWKnq6GgQxK7UlNAAknWgUADe6lDDvrb2AM7AxM0A5qkjUONhxChjjABGEhIhENQoqQC+6uqU+ZNQLFxQjD1Fxv2jdowA5ABiW88+SytrUFMRUAOjTUpxQ5zswAAFhIyNdYNlcvkELcKsYiNRiLY4D4wBjbNpEgMhiN0O4CJoIG50ZibHA5Lh8M9XFFKBh8s9eIM1AsFriaXBmEVuPMRkc1MThhAQuNoFyeSNBYIANp8rEAXSg1HGmpQPHwqps2hFwzFYvUEOhZAIz1Wdk+UGeACEMRzUhaYQRFVxCQ9LqAAHS26CM53EZ4HYVAA). I also copy the code here just in case:

```
type T1<Tentity> = (predicate: ((entity: Tentity) => Tentity | void)) => void;
type T2<TEntity> = (propertyName: keyof TEntity, newValue: unknown) => void;
type TCommon<TEntity> = T1<TEntity> | T2<TEntity>;

interface IEntity {
    name: string;
    surname: boolean;
}

const entity : IEntity = { name: 'Foo', surname: true };

const method : TCommon<IEntity> = (param1, param2) => {
    if (typeof(param1) === 'function') {
        param1(entity);
    }

    else {
        (entity[param1] as any)= param2;
    }
}

method('name', 'Bar');
method((entity) => { entity.name = 'Bar'});
```

As you can see, I expect both calls of `method` to work correctly.
From what I think, TypeScript/IntelliSense should be smart enough to make this reasoning:

- Since the first parameter is a `function`, then we have a `T1`, therefore I don't even need the second parameter.
- Otherwise, the first parameter is a string, thus we have a `T2`, thus I expect a second parameter as well.

Unfortunately, this is not what's happening: it seems TypeScript cannot "believe" that param1 can also be a function:

[image]

I'm pretty sure this can be done because we have the function overload, but I've been able to use them only inside a `class`. But it's basically the same thing, expect in this case I'm defining the `method` as a global variable.

Comment: Unions of functions result in an intersection of their parameter types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an interface to describe a set of call signatures:

```
interface TCommon<TEntity> {
    (predicate: ((entity: TEntity) => TEntity | void)): void
    (propertyName: keyof TEntity, newValue: unknown): void;
}
```

But we aren't quite done yet. The second parameter is optional in the sense that the first overload doesn't need a second parameter but the second overload does.

So we mark the second parameter as optional:

```
const method: TCommon<IEntity> = (param1, param2?: unknown) => {
```

And that's it.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WkMxjN)

Comment: Nice one, I was on the same track, but never thought about making param2 optional..  Obvious in hindsight.. :) UpVote..

Comment: I never had the idea to use an interface without.. properties, or at least, with properties used as a method signature. Nice.